# Blocky marks on colour negatives

Tags: film, developing, negative-film

I've recently started developing my own colour film with the [Tetenal C-41 kit](https://www.tetenaluk.com/colortec-c-41-negative-rapid-2-bath-kit-1l-1-102221). After scanning with my Epson V600 I've noticed that some of my frames have these blocky marks on them (see a few that I've circled in red below).

I've developed two rolls so far, one at 30°C and this one at 38°C, but some frames from both rolls have these blemishes on them.

Are these simply small water spots, or some kind of problem in my developing or scanning process?

[image]

Comment: These look like some kind of scanning artifact to me. They definitely don't look like water spots. Just to be sure, have you examined the negatives with a loupe?

Comment: @Kahovius Good point. I’ll need to invest in a loupe to double check, but I’ll try re-scanning first. Perhaps it’s Epson’s dust removal feature that’s introducing these artifacts.